# what does "EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB" mean in dpdk?

Tags: dpdk, suricata

I'm new to DPDK, and I'm installing a DPDK version of suricata on the server. When I run `suricata --list-dpdkports`, it shows

```
EAL: Detected 128 lcore(s)
EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
EAL: Multi-process socket /tmp/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB
EAL: Probing VFIO support...
EAL: Couldn't get fd on hugepage file
EAL: error allocating rte services array
EAL: FATAL: rte_service_init() failed
EAL: rte_service_init() failed
5/11/2020 -- 21:41:45 - <Error> - [ERRCODE: SC_ERR_DPDK_CONFIG(319)] -  DPDK init failed
```

What does `EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB` mean? No matter how many hugepages I set, it always show that.

```
AnonHugePages:    104448 kB
HugePages_Total:    8192
HugePages_Free:     8191
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:       2048 kB
```

I'm new to DPDK, and most of the solutions I found online is about `No Free hugepages reported`. I really wanna know what it means. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ericsun the log `EAL: No available hugepages reported in hugepages-1048576kB` is normal as your huge page is `2048 kB`. DPDK on x86 can use both 2MB or 1GB huge page. In function `rte_eal_init` both are probed. In your current setup, 1GB is not found. Hence rte_eal_init logs the same.

your error is

```
EAL: Couldn't get fd on hugepage file
EAL: error allocating rte services array
EAL: FATAL: rte_service_init() failed
```

Use `sudo` for elevating privellege and accessing hugepage via mmap.

Comment: Thanks, I'm really new to this. Again, thanks for your help!

Comment: if running with root privilege has helped you, please accept and upvote. If it has not I am available to for a live debug